# Prefix-Span does not find any patterns in the pickle file

Tags: python, sequence, pickle

I have a list of sequences in a Pickle file and have tried to data mine for common patterns using Prefix-Span. I did not get an error, but I also did not get any pattern output.

The pickle file contains data like this:

> Sequence 1: [-1, 2, 3, 4, 0, ...]
> Sequence 2: [0, 4, 1, 2, 0, ...]
> Sequence 3: [-1, 2, 0, -1, 0, ...]

The maximum length of a sequences is like 300 and there like 30 different sequences

I tried the following code:

```
import time
from prefixspan import PrefixSpan
import pickle


def pattern_finder(list_of_sequences, max_pattern_length=5):
    start_time = time.time()

    print(
        f' pattern mining with PreFixSpan {len(list_of_sequences[0] *       len(list_of_sequences))} points...')

    with open('my_pickle_file.pkl', 'rb') as pickle_file:
        data = pickle.load(pickle_file)
    ps = PrefixSpan(data)

    ps.maxlen = max_pattern_length

    patterns = ps.frequent(2, closed=True)

    end_time = time.time()
    duration = end_time - start_time
    print(f" Completion Time: {'{:.2f}'.format(duration / 60)} minutes.")

    print(f'Patterns found :{patterns}')

    return patterns


if __name__ in "__main__":
    with open('my_pickle_file.pkl', 'rb') as file:
        list_of_sequences = pickle.load(file)
    pattern_finder(list_of_sequences)
```

The pattern output is: Patterns found :[]

and I don't know why it is not finding any patterns.